# Lazy-loading images using an IntersectionObserver

Tags: javascript

As part of a progressive enhancement revision, I created a module, which should handle loading images lazily.

You can find a working example on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/lumoris/pen/aLjrzm/).

To each chuck of code below applies the following question: Am I accustomed to any bad coding habits? Would you do something different?

The image gets loaded, when the `loadImage` function is called, which can be passed an Image Element with a `data-lazy` attribute, or an URL and ultimately returns an Image element.

```
function loadImage(image) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const isImage = image instanceof Image || image instanceof HTMLImageElement;

    /*
     * Would this be a better case for writing the if statement out?
     */
    const url = isString(image)
      ? image
      : (isImage && 'lazy' in image.dataset ? image.dataset.lazy : null);

    if (!url) {
      throw new Error('An URL has to be provided.' + isImage ? 'The [data-lazy] attribute is not set.' : '');
    }

    image = isImage ? image : new Image();

    image.addEventListener('load', () => {
      resolve(image);
    });

    image.addEventListener('error', () => {
      reject(new Error('An error occurred while loading the image.'));
    });

    image.src = url;

  });
}
```

Then I added a `make` function, which returns a function which becomes handy, when I create the IntersectionObserver.

```
function makeLoadImage(doAfterLoad) {
  return (image) => loadImage(image).then((image) => doAfterLoad(image) || image);
}
```

The factory function which returns the IntersectionObserver. You can decide, whether the images on screen should be loaded simultaneously or in order, and you can define a duration before the image gets loaded, which essentially prevents someone triggering the images to get loaded, when scrolling/swiping quickly through the page.

```
function createIntersectionObserver(loadImage, options = {}) {

  if (!('IntersectionObserver' in window)) {
    throw new Error('The IntersectionObserver is not supported by this browser.'); 
  }

  options = {
    loadInOrder: false,
    wait: 100,
    ...options
  };

  const queue = Promise.resolve();
  const timeouts = new Map();

  const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      const { intersectionRatio, target: image } = entry,
        /* entry.isIntersecting is not supported on Android, Chrome 51.0.2704.81 */
        isIntersecting = intersectionRatio >= options.threshold;

      if (isIntersecting) {
        timeouts.set(image, setTimeout(() => {
          options.loadInOrder ? queue.then(() => loadImage(image)) : loadImage(image); 
          observer.unobserve(image);
          timeouts.delete(image);
        }, options.wait));
      } else if (!isIntersecting && timeouts.has(image)) {
        clearTimeout(timeouts.get(image));
      }

    });
  }, { ...options, threshold: [0, options.threshold] });

  return observer;

}
```

Finally, it is combined in `setup` function.

```
/**
 * Should I come up with a different name for this function,
 * if it is part of a module? It could be renamed, when it gets
 * imported by another module, but giving it a different name
 * in the first place would make it redudant to do after all.
 * So, I am guessing, "setup" as a name is too general, is it not?
 */
function setup(loadImage, images, options) {
  try {
    /* Progressive enhancement */
    const observer = createIntersectionObserver(loadImage, options);
    images.forEach((image) => observer.observe(image));
  } catch (error) {
    /* Fallback */
    images.forEach((image) => loadImage(image));
  }  
}
```

You can see the module in action on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/lumoris/pen/aLjrzm/).

What are your suggestions to improve my code?

Comment: I tested the conditions `image instanceof Image` and `image instanceof HTMLImageElement`. Both are `true` for all 4 images in the codepen - are there cases where one is `false` while the other is `true`?

Comment: I added `HTMLImageElement` to the condition, because an error occurred (in an individual case), when I tried passing them directly from the DOM to the `loadImage` function. I thought, this was unnecessary too, at first.